# 1. "X is a subset or part of y. x is true. so, y is true." 2. "x came from y. y is true. so x is true". Which fallacy are they?

Tags: logic, fallacies

example of the second argument.

'ad-duniya' (an arabic word) means 'nearer'. the word is denoted 115 times in Quran. In some cases the word 'ad-duniya' has been used for the meaning 'this world'. So the term 'world' is denoted 115 times in Quran.

Comment: The relationship between word ('ad-duniya') and object (the world) is not a relationship of set inclusion ...

Comment: #1 and #2 are different types of arguments. the example is for #2. #1 is about set.

Comment: Being a subset, a part, or coming from applies to objects or sets of objects. Being true or false applies to propositions. A chair a table or a piece of wood is not true or false, and "the chair is red" is not part of an object. You should reformulate your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is [Fallacy of Composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_composition), assuming what is true of a part is true of the whole.

2 is [Fallacy of Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_division), assuming what is true of the whole (the complete list of usages of "ad-duniya") is also true of a part (the proper subset of times that "ad-duniya" is meant as meaning "world").